# Can I use label for a label tag?

Tags: javascript, html

Usually I used label tag for pointing input tag like this

```
<label for='firstname'>First Name:</label>
<input type='text' id='firstname' />
```

Now I have this

```
<label for='firstname'>First Name:</label>
<label id='firstname'></label>
```

Since I haven't crossed anything like this before, is it possible to have `label` tag for a `label`.  Will it work, when I apply `Javascript` because I have to update the values? or this is a valid w3c compliance?

I'm confused whether to use it or not.

Comment: Have you tested it with http://validator.w3.org/ ?

Comment: Maybe that's why you're confused. You seem to be fundamentally misunderstanding the purpose of the `label` element.

Comment: Why would you want to?

Comment: According to this JSFiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/r9zx9/) it should work. I've given the first label an ID aswell so it can be accessed by Javascripts document.getElementByID

Comment: The `label` element is commonly used to focus an element, usually `input`... is there any other use that I don't know, or why would you want to focus a `label`?

Comment: this is very meta, labeling a label tag. where would this madness end?

Comment: @j08691 I have to construct like this `First Name: praveen` where praveen should be a label.  Which is tend to be dynamic.

Comment: You can use an `input` element as a label, just make the thing readonly and apply some CSS to it.  I'd say you are likely to encounter cross browser compatibility issues doing this.

Comment: The `for` attribute of the label element must refer to a form control.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. Label elements label (primarily) form controls (`<input>`, `<button>`, etc), not arbitrary elements.

See [the HTML specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#category-label):

> Some elements, not all of them form-associated, are categorized as labelable elements. These are elements that can be associated with a label element.
>
> `button`, `input` (if the type attribute is not in the hidden state), `keygen`, `meter`, `output`, `progress`, `select`, `textarea`

Comment: I'm trying to have like this `First Name: praveen`  Can I have it like `label: label(id='firstname')`.  So that I can update the value using id in JS?

Comment: You can use a span element instead. Labels are nothing special as far as "updating with JS" goes.

Comment: Thanks you, I go with `span`.

Comment: @Quentin Your span suggestion saved me lots of points off! Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

It's invalid according to the W3C validator.

> The `for` attribute of the label element must refer to a form control.

Comment: Thanks.  But can I use it without `for` attribute.  like this `First Name: praveen`  Can I have it like `label: label(id='firstname')`.  So that I can update the value using id in JS?  Is this still invalid?

Comment: If you use it without the `for` attribute, as in `<label>First name: <label id="firstname"></label></label>`, you would receive this error _The element label must not appear as a descendant of the label element._. You still can use it, but don't expect it to be valid HTML. It will still work well in most browsers (except for those accessibility-oriented).

Answer (score 2):

As others have answered, the `label` element must refer to a control, such as `input`, so it must not refer to another `label` element, even syntactically. This restriction is present even in HTML5.

This means that if you read user input using elements other than controls, you can still use labels for them, but you must not use `label` markup for the label. Normally, text data like names is best read using `input type=text`. If you cannot use it, or another control, for some reason, then the approach recommended in ARIA specifications is to a semantically neutral element, normally `span`, and use the ARIA attribute [`aria-labelledby`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Accessibility/ARIA/ARIA_Techniques/Using_the_aria-labelledby_attribute) to specify the connection between a label and the `span`. Example:

```
<span id=firstnameLabel>First Name:</span>
<span role=textbox id=firstname aria-labelledby=firstnameLabel></span>
```

The ARIA attributes are primarily meant for assistive or otherwise accessibility-aware software. They are probably ignored by mainstream browsers.

Comment: +1 Nice explanation.  Thank you for suggesting `span` and `aria` attribute.

Comment: The first version of my answer had `aria-describedby` in the code sample; now fixed to `aria-labelledby` (as in the text). The `aria-labelledby` corresponds to the relationship between a control and its `label`, and it is essential. The `aria-describedby` attribute may be used *additionally* to refer to more detailed explanations.

Answer (score 0):

Label for label is non-conforming. Probably [HTML5 `output` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-output-element) is what you want?

Answer (score 0):

The Label "For" attribute has to point to a valid ID attribute of a "control" element, http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/interact/forms.html#h-17.2 lists valid control elements as 
buttons, checkboxes, radio buttons, menus, file select, hidden controls, object controls.

It might work in JS, but it would be invalid HTML